# Consuming SOAP web service with ngx-soap in Angular 7

Tags: angular, web-services, soap, angular7

I am trying to use ngx-soap with an angular component, but I can't retrieve results from SOAP web service

const promise = this.soap.createClient('http://localhost:8080/javainuse/ws/helloworld.wsdl');
from(promise).subscribe(
client => (this.client = client)
);

I have the following SOAP envelope

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:jav="http://javainuse.com"> <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body> <jav:inputSOATest> <test>test</test> </jav:inputSOATest> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

and expected to get the following results "Hello Test" without the following envelope

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <SOAP-ENV:Header/> <SOAP-ENV:Body> <ns3:outputSOATest xmlns:ns3="http://javainuse.com"> <result>Hello test!</result> </ns3:outputSOATest> </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: finally, I have created a generic middleware using java, that parses any response from any SOAP web service to JSON object